# PHP determine longest value within a loop using strlen

Tags: php, loops

Within a PHP foreach loop I have a person's name looping. However, outside the loop I want to determine the largest length used within the loop. So I may have 6 names in the loop and most of them may be 6-8 characters long, but one might be 12 characters. So I would like to find the largest amount.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What do you have so far, and where do you get into trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$info = array();

$names = array("Name 1","Name 2","Name 3","This is the longest string","Name 4");

foreach($names as $key=>$value) {
    if(empty($info) || strlen($value) > $info[1]) {
        $info[0] = $key;
        $info[1] = strlen($value);
    }
}

echo 'The longest value is ', $names[$info[0]], ' which has ', $info[1], ' charachters and its array index is ', $info[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$longest = '';
foreach($names as $name) {
    if(strlen($name) > strlen($longest)) {
        $longest = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: why perfoming `strlen($longest)` every time

Comment: In PHP `strlen()` is most likely `O(1)`. So the overhead is minimal (just the function call).

Answer (score 1):

As a variation from the more obvious, consider a functional implementation:

```
$longest = array_reduce($names, function($longest, $candidate) {
    return strlen($longest) >= strlen($candidate) ? $longest : $candidate;
});
```